# BigBlueButton : Recommended System Requirements

Tags: bigbluebutton

I want to install BigBlueButton for university of which there will be several conferences in parallel (more than 10), most of conferences are point to point (2 participant).
I need the best quality of voice.
So what's the Recommended System Requirements to install BBB ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton.  You should be able to setup a BigBlueButton server that meets your use case by ensuring your server meets the minimum requirements (see link below).

The project offers an install script that can get you going in about 15 minutes.  For minimum server requirements and steps to install, see

https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bbb-install

Regards,... Fred